# select query to get all values and also distinct value

Tags: php, mysql

Hi i am trying to get distinct values and some other data from same table A . the code i tried is

```
$query2="select DISTINCT(from_id) from messages where to_id='$userid' order by messagedate DESC";
$res2=mysql_query($query2);
while($row2=mysql_fetch_row($res2))
{
$query="select * from messages where to_id='$userid' and from_id='$row2[0]' ORDER BY messagedate DESC"
```

using the above method i am unable to filter distinct values hence i tried like this

```
select msgid,DISTINCT(from_id) from messages where to_id='21' order by messagedate DESC
```

Its an error. need help pls

Comment: What kind of error did you get?

Comment: Both queries have the same logic at the first sight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into the `GROUP BY` statement

I think you need something like

```
SELECT    msgid, from_id 
FROM      messages
WHERE     to_id = 21
GROUP BY  from_id
ORDER BY  messagedata DESC
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
select DISTINCT(from_id),msgid from messages where to_id='21' order by from_id DESC
```

Comment: `DISTINCT` is not a function, it is an optional statement as part of the `SELECT` statement http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/distinct-optimization.html